# Rails 3.2.8 "New" does not find bundler on Windows 2008

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-server-2008-r2

I've just installed Ruby (1.9.3) and Rails (3.2.8) on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

```
E:\>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]

E:\>rails --version
Rails 3.2.8
```

Whenever I run "rails new" the following error occurs:

```
C:/Program Files/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/
generators/app_base.rb:254:in ``': No such file or directory - ""C:/Program File
s/Ruby/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe"" -rubygems "C:/Program Files/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/
gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/bin/bundle" install (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I've tried running "rails new" in different directories, and as administrator and ordinary users.

I think that bundler is properly installed:

```
E:\>gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.2.1)
```

Updating rails isn't helping either.

```
E:\>gem update rails
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

I have read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org.  If there is an answer for me there I do not understand it.

I understand that most everyone else is using a better OS, so please share only your sympathy.

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: I've moved on to another OS.  I advise others not to attempt rails on windows.